# Reference: Irreducible components of the Steinberg variety are conormal bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, rt.representation-theory

The (partial) Springer resolution is defined as a map $\mu: T^*\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{N}$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is the partial flag variety consisting of $n$-step partial flags of $\mathbb{C}^d$, and $\mathcal{N}$ a set of nilpotent operators $\mathcal{N} = \{X \in \text{End}(\mathbb{C}^d) : X^n = 0\}$. There's a characterisation of the cotangent bundle of the flag variety as the set of pairs $T^*\mathcal{F} = \{(X, F_\bullet) \in \mathcal{N} \times \mathcal{F} : XF_i \subset F_{i-1} \text{ for all } i\}$.

Using this characterisation, the Steinberg variety is the fibred product $Z = T^*\mathcal{F} \times_\mathcal{N} T^*\mathcal{F}$, alternatively written as the set of triples $Z = \{(X, F_\bullet, F_\bullet'):\dots\}$. There is a standard result that this variety is the union of conormal bundles to the $GL_d(\mathbb{C})$-diagonal orbits in $\mathcal{F} \times \mathcal{F}$, see e.g.  Chriss-Ginzburg Prop 4.1.6 or 3.3.4.

On the other hand, the Bruhat decomposition tells us that these diagonal orbits are parametrised by elements of the corresponding Weyl group (in this case, $S_n$ the symmetric group). It is another standard fact that the *irreducible components* of the Steinberg variety are the (closures of the) conormal bundles to these orbits, see e.g. Chriss-Ginzburg Corollary 3.3.5.

I'm looking for either a proof of this result, or at the very least a good moral reason for why this should be true.

This is a repost of the question I asked on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3770964/irreducible-components-of-the-steinberg-variety-are-conormal-bundles-reference).

Comment: Does this not follow from the fact that these conormal bundles are connected (so their closures are irreducible) and all of the same dimension (so must be components)?

Comment: After thinking about it, why do we need the equi-dimension property? I don't think the conormal bundles aren't all of the same dimension in general.

Comment: The conormal bundle to a submanifold $Z \subseteq X$ is a lagrangian submanifold of $T^\ast X$. In particular it has dimension $=dim(X)$.

Comment: Ah, I missed the fact that you were looking at the space of *all* partial flags. This is a disjoint union of manifolds of different dimension. Of course, what I wrote above applies in the case of $X$ connected (e.g. $Fl_d$ for a fixed dimension vector $d$).

Comment: If you have a variety which is a finite union of locally closed subvarieties all of the same dimension then their closures will all be top dimensional irreducible closed subsets, and thus irreducible components. The equidimensionality is crucial here (think of the affine line as a union of the origin and the punctured affine line - certainly the origin is not an irreducible component of the affine line). I had in mind applying this for each connected component of $Fl \times Fl$ at a time. Perhaps I have totally misunderstood your question though - apologies if so!